# For what $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does $\int^\infty_0 e^{ax}\sin x dx$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For what $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does the integral $\qquad \int^\infty_0 e^{ax}\sin x dx \qquad$ exist and find the integral for those values.
My problem is that the result of the given solution is slightly different, but since they use a different method that I don't really understand, I don't know where my mistake is. I'd appreciate it if somebody could point out my mistake(s). Thank you.

This is my take:
$\int e^{ax}\sin x dx=-e^{ax}\cos x+a\int e^{ax}\cos xdx$
$\qquad \qquad \quad =-e^{ax}\cos x+a\ (e^{ax}\sin x -\frac{1}{a}\int e^{ax}\sin x dx)$
$\qquad \qquad \quad =-e^{ax}\cos x +ae^{ax}\sin x-\int e^{ax}\sin xdx$
$\qquad \quad \qquad = \frac{ae^{ax}\sin x - e^{ax}\cos x}{2}$
$\int^\infty_0 e^{ax}\sin x dx=\lim_{b\to \infty} [\frac{ae^{ax}\sin x - e^{ax}\cos x}{2}]^b_0$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad = \lim_{b\to \infty} (\frac{ae^{ab}\sin b - e^{ab}\cos b}{2}-\frac{ae^{0}\sin 0 - e^{0}\cos 0}{2})=\lim_{b\to \infty} (\frac{ae^{ab}\sin b - e^{ab}\cos b}{2}+\frac{1}{2})$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad =\frac{1}{2}\lim_{b\to \infty} (e^{ab}(a\sin b-\cos b)+1)$

However this is the given solution:
$\int^\infty_0 e^{ax}\sin x dx=\lim_{b\to \infty} \int^\infty_0 \text{Im} (e^{(a+i)x})dx $
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad = \lim_{b\to \infty} [\text{Im} \frac{e^{(a+i)x}}{a+i} ]^b_0$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad = \lim_{b\to \infty} [ \frac{1}{a^2+1} \ \text{Im}((a-i)e^{(a+i)x}]^b_0$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad =\lim_{b\to \infty} [ \frac{1}{a^2+1} \ \text{Im}((a-i)e^{ax}(\cos x + i\sin x))]^b_0$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad =\lim_{b\to \infty} [ \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+1} (a\sin x-\cos x)]^b_0$
$\qquad \qquad\ \ \quad =\frac{1}{a^2+1}\lim_{b\to \infty} (e^{ab}(a\sin b-\cos b)+1) $

As you can see, the difference is that I got $\frac{1}{2}$ before the lim whereas the correct term in that spot is $\frac{1}{a^2+1}$. I don't really see where I went wrong but I also don't really understand the correct answer. Thank you. (The rest of the question is not an issue by the way)

Comment: I think that you need to wrote $a$ instead of $\frac1a$ in the second integral

Comment: @Masacroso you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it should be
$$\begin{align}\int e^{ax}\sin x dx&=-e^{ax}\cos x+a\int e^{ax}\cos xdx\\  
&=-e^{ax}\cos x+a\ (e^{ax}\sin x -a\int e^{ax}\sin x dx)\\  
&=-e^{ax}\cos x +ae^{ax}\sin x-a^2\int e^{ax}\sin xdx\\  
&= \frac{ae^{ax}\sin x - e^{ax}\cos x}{1+a^2}+C
\end{align}$$
Then the correct result follows: for $a<0$
$$\int^\infty_0 e^{ax}\sin x dx=\frac{1}{1+a^2}.$$
For $a\geq 0$ the improper integral is not convergent.